# How to schedule a task by setting ETA using gocelery module?

Tags: go, celery

I want to schedule a task such that it should come after some ETA (i.e.,10 sec) only for one time (not periodically) using gocelery module.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "it should come after..." ? Do you mean it should start to execute, or do you mean it should end ? What does ETA mean ? Expected Time of Arrival ?

Comment: ETA-estimated time of arrival  ...like countdown param in gocelery module

Comment: Did you find a solution @VaniPolnedi ?